# Iterate over an ordered dictionary after a certain key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, iterator

I've the following dictionary

```
desc = {'city': 'Monowi', 'state': 'Nebraska', 'county':'Boyd', 'pop': 1}
desc =  OrderedDict({k: desc [k] for k in desc})
```

I can iteration through the keys and values of the dictionary in the following way

```
 for k, vin desc .items():
```

Let's say I want to start iterating from the key 'country', I am not sure how this can be done.

Any suggestions will be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way, although, there's likely something more succinct:

```
desc = {'city': 'Monowi', 'state': 'Nebraska', 'county': 'Boyd', 'pop': 1}
keyList = list(desc.keys())
start = keyList.index('county')

for i in range(start, len(desc)):
    key = keyList[i]
    value = desc[key]
    print(f"{key} -> {value}")
```

Output is:

```
county -> Boyd
pop -> 1
```